# Writing data from Kinesis to S3

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am writing data using the AWS SDK from a Java application that posts data to a Kinesis stream. This is done in batches of 10 records at once, using the following code;

```
// Convert to JSON object, and then to bytes...
                ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
                String json = ow.writeValueAsString(transaction);

                // Add byte array to PutRecordsRequestEntry
                PutRecordsRequestEntry record = new PutRecordsRequestEntry();
                record.setPartitionKey(String.valueOf(java.util.UUID.randomUUID()));
                record.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(json.getBytes()));

                // Add to list...
                batch.add(record);

                // Check and send batches
                if(counter>=batchLimit){

                    logger.info("Sending batch of " + batchLimit + " rows.");

                    putRecordsRequest.setRecords(batch);
                    PutRecordsResult result = amazonKinesisClient.putRecords(putRecordsRequest);
                    batch = new ArrayList<>();
                    counter=0;

                }else{
                    counter++;
                }
```

Then I have a nodejs lambda function that is triggered on every transaction received on Kinesis, and the idea is for it to write transactions coming in from Kinesis, and put them into a firehose stream of data for them to be saved to S3.

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    console.log(event);

    var params = {
        DeliveryStreamName: "transaction-postings",
        Record: { 
            Data:  decodeURIComponent(event)
        }
    };
    firehose.putRecord(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else    {  
            console.log(data);           // successful response
        }

        context.done();
    });
};
```

However when looking at data on S3, all I see is the following, and not the JSON list of objects as I was expecting...

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Can anybody please point to me what am I missing to stream data from Kinesis to s3, as JSON objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data:  decodeURIComponent(event)
```

You need to serialise the event, as Lambda automatically de-serialises arguments. i.e.:

```
Data: JSON.stringify(decodeURIComponent(event))
```

Comment: Just did the change, and still getting "[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]""[object  as a result.

Comment: Actually when I changed that line of code to "Data: event", I got for example in S3 : {"Records":[{"kinesis":{"kinesisSchemaVersion":"1.0","partitionKey":"2a4bb9d9-a023-4c03-8616-ef3e7c567459","sequenceNumber":"49571132156681255058105982946244422009241197082071531522","data":"ewogICJyb3dJZCIgOiA3MjEzMTU0NSwKICAi...... Why don't I get the actual JSON Object sent above?

Comment: I think it's because when setting the data record.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(json.getBytes()))... I need to convert back to utf8.

Comment: That format is what you normally receive from lambda with kinesis. Take each data element, decode it (it's in base64) and you'll get the original

Comment: Accepting yours as answer as you led me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering the code changes required... To write to S3 the actual messages sent from the producer, the data property of the PutRecordsRequestEntry needs to be decoded. In other words, these code blocks show the dependency used, the lambda to parse data from the Kinesis stream...

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
var firehoseStreamName = "transaction-postings";

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    // This is the actual transaction, encapsulated with Kinesis Put properties
    var transaction = event;

    // Convert data object because this is all that we need
    var buf = new Buffer(transaction.data, "base64");

    // Convert to actual string which is readable
    var jsonString = buf.toString("utf8");

    // Prepare storage to postings firehose stream...
    var params = { 
        DeliveryStreamName: firehoseStreamName, 
        Record: { 
            Data:  jsonString
        }
    };

    // Store data!
    firehose.putRecord(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {

            // This needs to be fired to Kinesis in the future...
            console.log(err, err.stack); 
        }
        else{  
            console.log(data);            
        }

        context.done();
    });
};
```

This is because a record sent using the AWS producer dependency below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Would look like this;

```
{
  "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
  "partitionKey": "cb3ff3cd-769e-4d48-969d-918b5378e81b",
  "sequenceNumber": "49571132156681255058105982949134963643939775644952428546",
  "data": "[base64 string]",
  "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1490191017.614
}
```